# What is the proper letter case to use in VHDL?

Tags: syntax, vhdl

The last few days I'm writing some VHDL code for my final project. I'm quite used to languages having a common-accepted syntax, for example, the letter case for variables, constants, keywords, etc. However, in VHDL, case-insensitivity makes the language quite easy to write when you're a newbie, but after a while your code looks a total mess!

My confusion comes also from the fact that, for example, in [Volnei Pedroni's "Circuit Design with VHDL"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262162245) keywords like **architecture** or **begin** are written in capitals. On the other hand, when Xilinx tools autogenerate some code, these particular keywords are in lowercase.

**The actual question:**

Is there a "good-habit" or a common industry practice about the issue? I know that it isn't THAT important, but I'd like to know how the professionals manage this kind of issues.

Comment: Of course opinion based, but as you noticed it is important to have a opinion on this; otherwise it gets messy.  The subject is beyond coding letter case, so see suggestions at [VHDL coding style](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vhdl+coding+style).  Top of my list are: Keywords and identifiers as all lower case, except constants as all upper case.  For port names append "_i" on inputs and "_o" on outputs, since that will help you a lot determining connectivity in a structural module.

Comment: There's no right answer. A good habit is to adopt a good habit. Be consistent. Consider using case to differentiate between VHDL keywords (entity, process etc) and your identifiers (signal names etc).

Comment: Normally a corporation or even a large project will have its own coding style guide. Casing and code formatting (tabs vs spaces etc) will be covered in this, along with more detailed requirements on commenting, allowed types in ports, allowed libraries etc. As with Ada, CamelCase is often deprecated in favour of underscores to separate words, but that's not universal.

Comment: Personally, I hate code that yells at me. `ARCHITECTURE XD_LOL IS SIGNAL LMAO : STD_LOGIC; BEGIN LMAO <= X'D'; END ARCHITECTURE;` like calm down boy. If you want to write code like that, consider switching to LOLCODE.